# Dialog box in Adobe reader is scrambled

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-reader

I use win 7 and Adobe reader 11. After updating from ADobe reader 9 to 10 (automatically) I can´t see a proper dialog boxx when i print the PDF. EIther it har veryyyyy big letters or the text is missing in the Printing option box. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall several times, but there is no difference. 
I have also tried to download the sherife sans font.
When I hade Adoobe reader 8, there was no problem.
On an other computer I had the same problem, but I could resolve it by uninstalling and reinstallation Adobe reader.

Rutred

Answer (score 0):

This is almost always a function of the printer driver.  First check the mfr's website to see if there are updated drivers available, or else use a different printer with a different driver.

Then check to see if you are using PCL5e, PCL6, Postscript, or a Universal driver.  Usually the most successful driver is the Postscript driver, but if you want PCL functionality, just switch to the alternate of 5e or 6.